# OpenGL Blend Function To Copy RBG/Disregard Alpha?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

There may be an easier way to do this, I can do it with a shader I'd imagine, but I feel like setting the blend function is simpler.

Shader would maybe be `gl_FragColor = vec4(texture.rgb, 0);`

For a reason, I need to have a freshly cleared FBO filled with a transparent (0) texture. That way the pixels in the FBO are visually transparent, but contain the RGB values of the texture.

It's tough to explain, but it's essentially a `glClear()` but with a texture rather than a solid color. Is there a combination blend src/dst function that would accomplish this?

Basically it shouldn't matter what the FBO looks like beforehand. I then want to render a texture to it, but since I'm rendering it with alpha 0, it's not overriding the existing FBO pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do this via blending, you can do this via the separate blend factors introduced originally in [`GL_EXT_blend_func_separate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_blend_func_separate.txt) (promoted to OpenGL core functionalitiy in Version 2.0):

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO, GL_ZERO, GL_ZERO);
glBlendEquation(GL_ADD); // is the default anyway
```